Can't make the classes "communicate"
Im trying to start an extra Thread, im using pyqt6
Here is my main class :
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MenuApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Inside it i have some UI components and my init where i start a seperate thread in a device where i get some data from it:
class MenuApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.calibration_thread = Thread(target=self.start_source_cal)
        self.calibration_thread.start()

This is my class from where i try to send the data :
class source_cal:
    def __init__(self, delayTime):

    def __source_sweep_worker(self):
        global AUData
        #calculations =a_units

        AUData = a_units
        arbitary_units = []

Here is my plot where i try to retreive that data(Seperate class) :

class PlotScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

    def update_plot_data(self):
        if self.scanning:
            x_data = self.calibratedWavelength()
            y_data =   # Fetch AUData from source_cal
            self.update_plot(x_data, y_data)

How i can get that array (AUData) and pass it in my PlotScreen in order to display the data  in my Plot?
Thanks.

For future reference, please consider: 1. providing an appropriate [mre]; 2. use more consistent and conventional naming standard (see the official Style Guide for Python Code); 3. avoid globals, especially when dealing with multithreading or multiprocessing, as they can result in unexpected behavior and bugs that are extremely difficult to track down; 4. use appropriate terminology (your "my main class" is not a class).
